# How many homomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z_{20}$ onto $\Bbb Z_{8}$? How many are there to $\Bbb Z_{8}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many homomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z_{20}$ onto $\Bbb Z_{8}$? How many
are there to $\Bbb Z_{8}$?

I can see that there are no onto homomorphisms because $|\Bbb Z_{20}|/ |\Bbb Z_{8}|$ is not an integer, but for "to" I can't figure how to solve this.  I can see that the trivial homomorphism and the natural one $\phi(x) = x\mod8$ work, but I can't see how I would find others.
I can also see that $|\phi(\Bbb Z_{20})| = 1, 2, $ or $4$ because it divides  $\Bbb Z_{20}$ and $\Bbb Z_{8}$, but from here I'm stuck too.

Comment: There may be a typo before "not being an integer".

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: The "natural" one is not a homomorphism. The answer gives a reason why. Differently, note that this natural one would be onto, which you just excloded correctly.

Comment: Under which operation?  If the group operation is multiplication, I see more possibilities.

Comment: Under addition modulo.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is cyclic, a homomorphism $\phi$ is determined by where it sends a generator $x$. So there are $|\mathbb{Z}_8|=8$ total candidate homomorphisms. Which of these are valid?

Note that we must have $\phi(x)^{20}=1$ and $\phi(x)^8=1$.